# Chrome and Firefox running ALWAYS in headless mode through Gitlab-runner

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, testcafe

I'm setting up a new e2e tests with Testcafe v1.3.3 using gitlab CI. The test are running in a windows machine there the Gitlab-runner running with shell executor. 
When tests are started on Chrome,Firefox and Edge, only Edge is displayed the GUI the other browsers are not displaying the GUI and just background processes that start, despite that Testcafe is configured to run without headless mode for Chrome and Firefox. However, the tests jobs run and tests fail/successes as expected.

Is this a correct behavior that Chrome and Firefox not showing GUI when headless mode is not given in the configuration?

Testcafe configuration file

.testcaferc.json

```
{
  "browsers": ["edge", "chrome", "firefox"],
  "debugMode": false,
  "debugOnFail": false,
  "developmentMode": false,
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "port1": "5050",
  "port2": "5051",......
}
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - test
Install_run_test:
  stage: test
  tags: 
    - windows
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm test
```

I expect to se the Chrome and Firfox GUI when running the e2e tests with Testcafe

Comment: Are you running gitlab-runner as service? Refer the following thread, it might help you run tests with GUI: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1046

Comment: @DmitryOstashev THX for your answer, I couldn't see the GUI because the gitlab-runner needed to run as Super-user permission.

Comment: I'm happy to hear you have found a solution. I'll sum it up and post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GitLab Runner requires super-user permissions to run the GUI. See the [Super-User Permission](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#super-user-permission) topic for more information.

If you run GitLab Runner on Windows as a service, you can find helpful tips in [this thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1046).